# Is it okay to use a different JDK from what my team use?

Tags: java, open-source, oracle

I am a new hire (as a software engineer) in a company and the Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) machine I got has no java installed. I tried to install Java SE 8 kit from Oracle but apparently there is a new licensing model (in which I am not familiar with) and you have to create an account before you can download their JDK. My question is okay to install OpenJDK in my machine for development while my team uses Oracle's JDK in their machines. Or should I just create an account and download Oracle's JDK and use it for development? My worry is there would some kind of conflict regarding Oracle's new licensing model because I would be developing using their JDK for production use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk with your company's IT department. If your business uses commercially-licensed software for your products, they should have a process for getting a license for developers. Never use software that could get your company into legal trouble without obtaining permission. If you aren't sure, ask.

As far as the technical compatibility goes, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22358071/389146). In a nutshell, they try to be the same, but there are subtle differences that in rare cases can be very important. You can get away most of the time with using a different one, but in general, you should try to use the same JDK that is used in production.